# Permitir diferentes tipos de datos en un mismo campo - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo una consulta de logica del cual no estoy muy seguro de como resolver, estoy realizando una especie de encuesta, en el cual, a la hora de crear las preguntas, necesito especificar el tipo de respuesta que esta recibira, ya sea una cadena de texto, un dato booleano, un dato numerico, etc. Sin embargo el campo de la base de datos lo tengo guardado por defecto como "string", dentro de la tabla "Answer" ¿de que forma podria permitir cualquier tipo de dato, especificamente en el campo llamado "response" y que a la hora de llamarlo a la vista regrese como tal? Agradezco sus sugerencias

**question.rb**

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :survey, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**answer.rb**

```
class CreateAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :answers do |t|
      t.string :response
      t.references :question, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo haría sería [serializar](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) el campo.

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :response
end
```

Y en la bd dejar el campo como `t.text :response` en vez de `string`, así te guardaría cualquier tipo de dato en un mismo campo, incluidos hashes u objetos, y después lo recuperarías tal cual al consultarlos.

Comment: Saludos Alter! Te agradezco muchisimo hayas contestado, ¿a la hora de realizar el llamado en la vista, se hace de forma normal? es decir <%= @object.response %>

Comment: @HectorHernandez sí, claro. Al deserializarse, se genera el mismo objeto del mismo tipo con los mismos valores que tenías en un inicio. Y si quieres limitarlo a un tipo específico, por ejemplo quieres que te guarde solo hashes en la bd, puedes restringirlo pasándole la clase como parámetro `serialize :response, Hash`, aunque al parecer este no es tu caso. Saludos

Comment: Te agradezco Alter! Saludos! =D